# Compare 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have 2 dictionaries, among them 1st have 266 entries and 2nd dictionary has 136. So by comparing both dictionary i want results which is not matched.

For e.g dic 1 have 130 more data then  dic 2. So i need those 130 unmatched data.

Any logic for this?

Thank you

Comment: Loop through one dictionary and see if each element is in the other dictionary.

Comment: I did it. However, for dic 1, it is matching with only 1 entry and not matching with other 135. So i am getting other 135 faulty results.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, If possible show us the example from both dictionaries. As a problem and the needed logic it looks straight forward. Perhaps your data will give us better idea. :)

Comment: are you looking to see if the keys in one are keys in the other?

Answer (score 2):

**Python 2:**

Assuming by 'entry' you mean 'key', a solution is to use set difference on the dictionary keys with something likee `set(dict1.keys()) - set(dict2.keys())`

Example:

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> b = {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
>>> a.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
>>> b.keys()
['a', 'c']
>>> set(a.keys())-set(b.keys())
set(['b', 'd'])
>>>
```

With `set(dict1.keys()) ^ set(dict2.keys())` you would get the set of keys that are in either dictionary but not in both.

**Python 3**

The `keys()` method of dictionaries in Python 3 directly support the set difference (`-`) and symmetric difference (`^`) so you can write

```
dict1.keys() - dict2.keys()
dict1.keys() ^ dict2.keys()
```

Comment: Would you still need to do `set()` on `set(dict.keys()) ^ set(dict2.keys())` if you using the `XOR` operation? Wouldn't `dict1.keys() ^ dict2.keys()` suffice?

Comment: `.keys()` returns a list, and the `^` operator is not defined on lists. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'list'`

Comment: Hm. Is this for `python2.7` by any chance? I tried the example you showed without `set()` and it outputs the same as with `set()` as I suggested. `In [25]: type(a.keys())
Out[25]: dict_keys` on `python3.7`.

Comment: @hqkhan: you are right. Python 3.7 dictionary keys are not `list`s, they are of type `dict_keys`, which supports set difference and symmetric difference. I update my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Are we assuming that the dictionary of 266 elements contains the same 130 entries as the smaller dictionary plus an additional 136?

If so, you could create an third empty dictionary and loop through the larger one to see if that entry is in the smaller dictionary. If not then add it to the new dictionary.

```
newdict = {}
For item in largerdict:
  if item not in smallerdict:
    newdict[item] = largerdict[item]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating a new dictionary without the elements of another, using python 3 dictionary comprehension syntax:

```
big_dict = {'t2': 2, 't': 1}
small_dict = {'t': 1}
new_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in big_dict.items() if k not in small_dict}
print(new_dict)
```